# Need generic method for converting to objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to do data binding for MVC controller,
therefore i need a generic class that will turn my classes from:

```
public class Subsystem
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need a generic method that will turn this:

```
public Subsystem[] GetSubsystems()
{
    return new Subsystem[]
               {
                   new Subsystem() {Id=1, Name = "A"},
                   new Subsystem() {Id=2, Name = "B"},
                   new Subsystem() {Id=3, Name = "C"}
               };

}
```

into this:

```
public object[] GetSubsystems()
{
    return new object[]
               {
                   new object[] {Id=1, Name = "A"},
                   new object[] {Id=2, Name = "B"},
                   new object[] {Id=3, Name = "C"}
               };
}
```

Comment: In general C# is probably not the right language to be using if you want duck typing.

Comment: object[] does not have Id and Name properties... I'm not sure if that's what you want to do.

Comment: did you mean anonymous types? like `new {Id = 1, Name = "A"}`?

Comment: Way too vague. You need to show what you are trying to use this with as what you are suggesting here may not actually be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think this may not be the best solution for what you're really after, but you can use Linq to transform it to an array of anonymous objects:

```
public static object[] GetSubsystems()
{
    Subsystem[] subsystems = new Subsystem[]
                                 {
                                     new Subsystem() {Id=1, Name = "A"},
                                     new Subsystem() {Id=2, Name = "B"},
                                     new Subsystem() {Id=3, Name = "C"}
                                 };

   object[] anonymousSubsystems = (from subsystem in subsystems
                                   select (object)(new { Id = subsystem.Id, Name = subsystem.Name })).ToArray();

    return anonymousSubsystems;
}
```

What you have in your "this" is not actually possible, your result from the Linq query I gave would be equivalent to:

```
public object[] GetSubsystems() 
{ 
    return new object[] 
                { 
                    new {Id=1, Name = "A"}, 
                    new {Id=2, Name = "B"}, 
                    new {Id=3, Name = "C"} 
                }; 
}
```